# I am facing slowness in getting streaming data while working with kafka

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am facing **lags while working with kafka streaming**, there is **no lag or slowness while it is snapshot ting data** but when it **starts its streaming** I am facing lags which is **starting from 10 mins and it increased gradually**. I am using **debezium** as source connector and getting all data on **console consumer**.

Content Of Kafka server.properties file is as follows:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=1

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of #max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

connect-distributed.properties File is as follows:

```
##
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
##

# This file contains some of the configurations for the Kafka Connect distributed worker. This file is intended
# to be used with the examples, and some settings may differ from those used in a production system, especially
# the `bootstrap.servers` and those specifying replication factors.

# A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# unique name for the cluster, used in forming the Connect cluster group. Note that this must not conflict with consumer group IDs
group.id=connect-cluster

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

# Topic to use for storing offsets. This topic should have many partitions and be replicated and compacted.
# Kafka Connect will attempt to create the topic automatically when needed, but you can always manually create
# the topic before starting Kafka Connect if a specific topic configuration is needed.
# Most users will want to use the built-in default replication factor of 3 or in some cases even specify a larger value.
# Since this means there must be at least as many brokers as the maximum replication factor used, we'd like to be able
# to run this example on a single-broker cluster and so here we instead set the replication factor to 1.
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
#offset.storage.partitions=25

# Topic to use for storing connector and task configurations; note that this should be a single partition, highly replicated,
# and compacted topic. Kafka Connect will attempt to create the topic automatically when needed, but you can always manually create
# the topic before starting Kafka Connect if a specific topic configuration is needed.
# Most users will want to use the built-in default replication factor of 3 or in some cases even specify a larger value.
# Since this means there must be at least as many brokers as the maximum replication factor used, we'd like to be able
# to run this example on a single-broker cluster and so here we instead set the replication factor to 1.
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

# Topic to use for storing statuses. This topic can have multiple partitions and should be replicated and compacted.
# Kafka Connect will attempt to create the topic automatically when needed, but you can always manually create
# the topic before starting Kafka Connect if a specific topic configuration is needed.
# Most users will want to use the built-in default replication factor of 3 or in some cases even specify a larger value.
# Since this means there must be at least as many brokers as the maximum replication factor used, we'd like to be able
# to run this example on a single-broker cluster and so here we instead set the replication factor to 1.
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
#status.storage.partitions=5

# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# List of comma-separated URIs the REST API will listen on. The supported protocols are HTTP and HTTPS.
# Specify hostname as 0.0.0.0 to bind to all interfaces.
# Leave hostname empty to bind to default interface.
# Examples of legal listener lists: HTTP://myhost:8083,HTTPS://myhost:8084"
#listeners=HTTP://:8083

# The Hostname & Port that will be given out to other workers to connect to i.e. URLs that are routable from other servers.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.
#rest.advertised.host.name=
#rest.advertised.port=
#rest.advertised.listener=

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
# any combination of: 
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Examples: 
plugin.path=kafka_sit/libs

#config providers configuration that allow for externalisation of commonlyused properties/secrets
config.providers=file
config.providers.file.class=org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
```

Content Of Debezium Connector Configurations:

```
{
    "name": "xstream_008",
    "config":
    {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
        "database.user": "dbzuser",
        "database.password": "abc",
        "database.hostname": "000.000.00.0",
        "database.port": "1234",
        "database.dbname": "databaseName",
        "database.pdb.name": "PDBNAME",
        "database.server.name": "SERVERNAME",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.DBZ",
        "table.include.list": "TABLENAME",
        "database.history.store.only.captured.tables.ddl" : true,
        "snapshot.select.statement.overrides" : "TABLENAME",
        "snapshot.select.statement.overrides.TABLENAME" : "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME",
        "database.out.server.name": "dbzxout",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
        "decimal.handling.mode":"double",
        "task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms": "20000",
        "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
        "offset.flush.interval.ms":10000,
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms":60000,
        "log.mining.batch.size.min":10000,
        "log.mining.batch.size.max":200000,
        "log.mining.batch.size.default":50000,
        "log.mining.view.fetch.size":20000,
        "time.precision.mode":"connect"
        
    }
}
```

Topic creation command :

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic mytopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1  --config retention.ms=172800000
```

I have configured **xstream user on oracle**, approach which we have used is **logminer** and not golden gate.

Can anyone assist me on where I am doing anything wrong, is there anything at **kafka/debezium configurations end** or it is at infra or should I need to ask **DBA to manage archive logs** more properly ?

Comment: You should profile each JVM process to see where the bottlenecks are